# Datetimepicker not formatting

Tags: jquery

I am using the DTP (jQuery) and trying to format the time and date like this:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                timeFormat:  "hh:mm:ss"

            });
```

But it is always showing this format:

```
2016/06/15 13:20
```

Also tried ' instead of " - but nothing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format:'yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
});
```

Docs: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Argh, overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<button id="showit">show</button> <div id="result"></div>
```

```js
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
   var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
   return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
}
    

$('#showit').click(function(){
    var d = new Date,
        dformat = [ (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
                    d.getDate().padLeft(),
                    d.getFullYear()].join('/')+
                    ' ' +
                  [ d.getHours().padLeft(),
                    d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
                    d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
     $('#result').html(dformat);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showit">show</button> <div id="result"></div>
```